# Claims Based Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project I'm working on. It's using Thinktecture Identitity Server to pass the token to my application. Problem is I need to extract a claim value from the token, so far I was able to do Linq query to get the claim value (I am able to see it in result via debug), however I can't pull the actual value out, I've tried to string, toarray, etc. It keeps giving me the actual type. My code is below:

```
var company = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.ToArray();
        var claimType1 = company[0].Claims.ToArray();
        var claimtest = from x in claimType1 where x.Type == "http://identityserver.thinktecture.com/claims/profileclaims/company" select x.Value;
        String claimfinal = claimtest.ToString();
        ViewBag.Message = claimtest.GetType().ToString() + "  " + claimfinal;
```

and this is the output:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Security.Claims.Claim,System.String]  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Security.Claims.Claim,System.String]
```

FYI:
This is in the controller only for testing purposes. Ideally I want to be able to process a claim, and store various info from it in a separate background class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`claimtest` is an IEnumerable, you probably want to select only the first claim of the specified type and then use its value:

```
var claimtest = claimType1
    .First(x => x.Type == "http://identityserver.thinktecture.com/claims/profileclaims/company")
    .Value;
```